# WPF: Making the Target property refer to a control in WindowsFormsHost

Tags: wpf, xaml

In WPF, you can assign a label a mnemonic, and tell it which control to activate with the "Target" property.

This doesn't work if the target is a WindowsFormsHost. Is there a known solution to this?

Here's an example. I am trying to make ALT-S activate the masked text box.

```
<Label 
   Width="Auto" 
   Target="{Binding ElementName=tbStartTime}" 
   TabIndex="12">
   _Start Time:
</Label>
<WindowsFormsHost 
    Name="tbStartTime" 
    TabIndex="13">
 <wf:MaskedTextBox Name="wfStartTime"  Mask="90:00" />
/WindowsFormsHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible, at least not without some extra boilerplate code... WPF and Windows Forms have a completely different model, and the `Target` property isn't designed to refer to WinForms controls.

Instead, I think you should use a WPF implementation of `MaskedTextBox`, like [this one](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2007/10/28/masked-textbox/) (you can find many other examples with Google). Using WinForms controls in a WPF app is rarely a good idea if you can avoid it...

EDIT: I just checked the doc : it is definitely not possible to do what you want, because the type of the `Label.Target` property is `UIElement`, and WinForms controls are clearly not `UIElement`s...

---

UPDATE: OK, I misread your code... you're referencing the `WindowsFormsHost`, which is a `UIElement`. Whoever voted me up was wrong too ;-)

I think the problem is that the `WindowsFormsHost` takes the focus when you press Alt-S, not the `MaskedTextBox`. Here's a quick workaround :

**XAML :**

```
<WindowsFormsHost 
    Name="tbStartTime" 
    TabIndex="13"
    GotFocus="tbStartTime_GotFocus">
 <wf:MaskedTextBox Name="wfStartTime"  Mask="90:00" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

**Code-behind :**

```
    private void tbStartTime_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        tbStartTime.Child.Focus();
    }
```

Anyway, my previous advice is still relevant : you'd better use a WPF MaskedTextBox...

Comment: That has to be a mistake by the WPF team. It's such an obvious thing - if you focus a WindowsFormsHost, what else should happen other than the child control becomes focused? Still, I'm happy there's a one-line workaround.

Comment: IMO, a really clean workaround wouldn't involve writing code behind... this one could easily be wrapped in a reusable attached property